# addEventListener paste for mac?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image hosting, and you can paste your clipboard with ctrl + v.
Now someone did contact me and told me it didn't work on his MAC
Is there a addEventListener for that?

Code i'm using for Windows:

```
<script>window.addEventListener("paste");</script>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your scrpt?

Comment: I'am only showing how i'm using it.